# How to allow guests to alter redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my web app, an authenticated user can pick songs from his spotify playlist to play at a party. I want guests (nonauthenticated users) to be able to view the picked songs and vote on their favorite songs on their own device (probably a phone), which means that they will be able to alter the state of the app.

I am using a Mongo, Express, React with Redux, Node full stack.

My plan is to store the picked songs and put it in my database and my app will generate a dynamically created react route that will GET request the songs from the database and display them on this route. The guests will only have access to this route.

How do I connect my guests to my app's redux store when they only have access to the route I give them? Is it even possible to connect them?

Comment: till he will able to dispatch an action,he can alter the state,you have to provide . reducers for it

Comment: It is not clear to me why in the third paragraph of your question you write that non-authenticated users do not have access to the redux store, and at the end of the question you ask if they can have access to the store... If you connect the Track component to the store with mapStateToProps you can access it...

Comment: I fixed the wording a little bit

Comment: Still I don't understand why the Track component cannot access the store like any other container component. Make it a class, mapStateToProps, and access the store...

Comment: Upon a page refresh, the redux store becomes reinitialized. Since my guests will have to manually to go the link I provide them, I think their store won't be the same as the one I have in my app. So, when they make dispatches, it will only be affecting their store and not mine

Comment: Then use redux-persist to to make the state persistent. Recommended. I had, however, some difficulties to make it work. Let me know if you want me to post my code.

Comment: All right, I"ll give that a shot

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments below, I hope that I understand now what you ask.

The application needs to always update the redux store to the latest contents of the database - regardless if it is a logged-in user or a guest. Both types of users need access to the store and should fire-up actions if and when they need to update the store.

redux-persist that I mentioned in the comments to the question takes care of making the state persistent in the browser, in case you refresh the page. May be needed as well (try to display a list of songs and then refresh the page), but not relevant to your question.

Comment: Will this work even if a guest accesses my route on their own device? In other words, will the store persist to their device?

Comment: Of course not. Now I see what you meant. The application needs to update the store from the database. The persist is useful for same device browser...

Comment: Okay, so then I think I need to expand on the backend API for the voting system. Do you think this will significantly slow down the performance of my app, considering how many database operations I might potentially have to make?

Comment: See my updated answer. Regarding performance - no other way to do it. If there are many users then you need more powerful hardware...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a middleware and add it to the store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";

const customMiddleWare = store => next => action => {
  if(store.user.isAuthenticated === true){
    next(action)
  }else{
    // You are only allowing non-authentic user to see the list. only those actions will be accessible to that user
    if(action.type === 'FETCH_SONGS'){
      next(action)
    }
  }
};
const middleware = [customMiddleWare];

const store = createStore(
  greetingReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
  compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);
```